# Keycloak does not start up correctly as a docker image

Tags: docker, jboss, keycloak

I give up! I simply cannot seem to run Keycloak as a docker container on my local. This is the command I use to start it up:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:12.0.2
```

Everything looks hunky dory while starting up:

```
23:31:37,488 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments
23:31:37,617 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS]
23:31:38,651 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "keycloak-server.war" (runtime-name: "keycloak-server.war")
23:32:02,704 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 0.0.0.0:8443
```

And then suddenly I see red logs on the console

```
00:06:09,373 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'add' at address '[
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]'
00:06:23,897 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.DeployerChainAddHandler$FinalRuntimeStepHandler@55b70d86 for operation add-deployer-chains at address [] failed -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:525)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1524)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1478)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1461)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$400(AbstractOperationContext.java:1325)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeResultHandlerPhase(AbstractOperationContext.java:877)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:727)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:468)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1415)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:529)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:515)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:477)
    at org.jboss.as.server@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:451)
    at org.jboss.as.server@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:404)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I don't get it, what more should I be doing? I'm following the official documentation from [here](https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-docker)

OTOH, I have been able to circumvent this by downloading and unzipping the TAR file, going to `bin` and running the `./standalone.sh` file. I face no issues starting up and running Keycloak then!

Comment: I just tested it on my machine and it worked flawlessly (using podman-docker instead of docker itself though). Additional information might help solving your problem: what docker version do you use? what OS are you using? Could you upload the complete log?

Comment: Yep I have also tested normally and it works so the problem is not the command per si

Comment: Sure, I'll add the full logs in a bit. I'm on MacOS Catalina and my docker version is 2.2.0.5

It ran successfully the VERY FIRST time. After that it would always just fail with that error.

Comment: Good to know that it ran successfully at least once. Did you do anything that could have broken the instance in any way?  
You could simply try to start from the beginning by removing the existing container. Use `docker container ls` to find out the container id, then use `docker container rm [CONTAINER ID]` to remove it (you have to replace `[CONTAINER ID]` with the actual id, of course)

Comment: @Saturnian Just out of curiosity: Did it work or did you run into the problem again? (or where you even able to reproduce the steps that might lead to the problem?)